# Jquery.inputmask not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

Trying to use Robin Herbots Inputmask module, and can't get it working. Looking at all the other similar posts, a common problem to make sure the docment.ready function has a call to inputmask(), but this looks good to me.

Scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
<script src="/js/jquery.inputmask.js">
<script src="/js/mainReady-client.js">
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

mainReady-client.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":input").inputmask();
});
```

HTML

```
<td>
  <input value="10" data-inputmask="'mask': '999'">
</td>
```

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#currIN").inputmask("9999");
});
```

or (the real one I want - currency)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#currIN").inputmask("'alias': 'numeric', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoGroup': true, 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': false, 'prefix': '$ ', 'placeholder': '0'");
});
```

and then:

```
<td>
  <input value="10" id="currIN">
</td>
```

It seems so simple yet nothing happens. It has to be the order that I load things, but it all looks good. Thanks for any help. Cheers.

Comment: Try http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ We've been using this plugin for all our projects without any issues.

Answer (score 10):

Try to use this inputmask script,

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
```

**[Working example JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/L530qmx5/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("#currIN").inputmask("9999");
  });
//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <td>
  <input value="10" id="currIN">
</td>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this CDN-

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.60/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js
```

A working demo is given here for you-

```js
$("#piash").inputmask("A-999");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.60/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>

<td>
  <input value="A-45" id="piash">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

While this question is old I believe I have found a solution for those with a similar problem. The noConflict() function fixed it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $j=jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(document).ready(function () {

        $j("#currIN").inputmask("9999");

    });
</script>
```

Comment: NoConflict just removes jQuery from the global namespace. If that fixed your problem it means you had another problem