# not working phone mask ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I try to develope MVC 5 web application in .Net Framework. I try to mask input on form .

How to make a similar mask for a phone number?

[image]

The code below does not work

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js">
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#phone').mask("+7(999)999-99-99");
</script>


<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <span style="font-weight: bold;">Phone:</span>
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phoneord, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "phone" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phoneord, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your script is before your html (and is trying to apply the plugin to an element which does not exist yet). Move your script to immediately before the closing `</body>` tag, or wrap in in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: change order script file first to jquery min file

Comment: that? <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>

Comment: whatever not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mentioning `inputmask` plugin (from `jquery.inputmask.bundle.js` referenced in your code), first you need to include all required dependencies as given in documentation there:

[Inputmask 3.x Documentation](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

Therefore, set the script order like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
```

From my experiments about this plugin, the `EditorFor` doesn't worked properly with it, hence you need to convert `EditorFor` to `TextBoxFor`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phoneord, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "phone" })
```

Then, activate masked input using lines below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#phone').inputmask("+7(999)999-99-99");
}
```

Note that if you encountered `$(...).mask is not a function` error in browser console, probably you must change `mask` to `inputmask`.

NB: If you intended to use [maskedInput plugin](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) instead (by mentioning `mask()` method on your code), change the script to this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

And then keep masking method as is:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
   $('#phone').mask("+7(999)999-99-99");
});
```

See [.NET Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QeoxYW) to see usage of both plugins.

Related issues:

[Jquery.inputmask not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510610/jquery-inputmask-not-working)

[Phone mask with jQuery and Masked Input Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery-and-masked-input-plugin)

Comment: Change this statement ".mask" on ".inputmask" resolve my problem